# curl: (52) Empty reply from server on Hive-Metastore

Tags: curl, tls1.3, self-signed-certificate, hive-metastore

While checking the connection of TLS enabled Hive-Metastore by using curl on --insecure(-k) gives `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. Checking without `-k` gives `curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate`.
To enable the TLS on Hive-Metastore, self signed certificates are created and added the following properties to the core-site.xml file.

```
<property>
    <name>metastore.use.SSL</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>metastore.keystore.path</name>
     <value>keystore.jks</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>metastore.keystore.password</name>
      <value>password</value>
 </property> `
```

`curl https://9.30.0.137:9083 -v` is used for checking. But when using `curl http://9.30.0.137:9083 -v` it works fine.
And also got another one is

```
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

How to check the connection of TLS enabled Hive-Metastore by using the curl command.